# R: Rolling rank of multivariate time series?

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I want to rank a set of variables every day (starting with a `zoo` series).

Here's an example:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- zoo(matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3), as.Date("2010-01-01") + 0:2)
colnames(x) <- letters[1:3]
```

The only way I know to do this is with `rollapply`, but this is quite slow.

```
>  rollapply(x, 1, rank, by.column=FALSE)
           a b c
2010-01-01 1 3 2
2010-01-02 1 2 3
2010-01-03 1 2 3
```

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

First off, thanks for sending a complete and reproducible example.

Secondly, I like your solution.  You may be hard-pressed to make it much faster yet keeping it simple.  One solution is to jst work on the underlying matrix (rather than the zoo object):

```
> X <- coredata(x)
> t(apply(X, 1, rank))
     a b c
[1,] 1 3 2
[2,] 1 2 3
[3,] 1 2 3
>
```

and to then re-attach the time index.  That may be faster, but not necessarily more defensive or more easily readable.

Comment: Thanks @Dirk!  Great suggestion.  I guess my reproducible example has limits in that it can't reproduce the speed factor on a large dataset.  But I suppose that can be inferred...

Comment: Yes, and that is the second step -- create some larger data and profile.  If there are low-hanging fruit, pick'em.  Else, there's always C/C++ if you really need the speed.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for C++ time series classes?

Comment: For times, I just use `as.numeric(index(x))` to create floats and pass those as a single vector.  For the rest, eg `coredata(x)`, I use a matrix -- and yes, I am somewhat partial to Rcpp and RcppArmadillo.  Maybe one day I'll sit down with Jeff and hash out how to bring some of the `xts` indexing closer to Rcpp.  So far, the basic vector and matrix solution worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going about this the right way.  Using `order` instead of `rank` is a bit faster, but I don't see how this is "quite slow".  Maybe you could elaborate a bit on your actual problem?

```
> system.time(for(i in 1:1000) rollapply(z, 1, order, by.column=FALSE))
   user  system elapsed 
      1       0       1 
> system.time(for(i in 1:1000) rollapply(z, 1, rank, by.column=FALSE))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.34    0.00    1.34
```

Comment: Thanks @Joshua!  Yes, the issue is that I'm working with some very long and wide time series.  This is not to say that this approach is slow in comparison to anything; just that I'm spending time counting sheep while it runs and was hoping for a more "vectorized" approach.